# Push Json filtered key values to nested ul with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, multidimensional-array

I need help pushing the values from a filtered json, I need this generate a nested ul list, I can not modify the json format at this point, I you check the console.log you will see the values to create the list, at this point I can't figure how to complete the 'for loop' to render the html markup needed, any help will be appreciated, this is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/43jh9hzz/, and if you check the console log you will see the values.

This is the Js:

```
                var json='';
            var property_set = new Set();
            function iterate(obj, stack)  {

                json="<ul>";

                for (var property in obj)  {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property))  {
                        if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                            iterate(obj[property], stack + '.' + property);
                        } 
                        else {
                            // console.log(property);
                            property_set.add(property);
                            json+="<li>";
                            if(typeof obj[property] !== "number") {
                            json+="<li>"+obj[property]+"</li>";
                            console.log(obj[property]);
                            }
                        }
                    } json += "</li>";
                }
            }

            var listEl = document.getElementById('output');
            iterate(jsonObj)
```

And this is the json format:

```
                var jsonObj = 
            {
                "level_1": [
                {
                    "level_1_name": "CiscoSingaporeEBC",
                    "level_2": [
                    {
                        "level_2_name": "Khoo Tech Puat",
                        "level_2_id": 2222,
                        "level_3": [
                        {
                            "name": "Boon Leong Ong",
                            "id": 6919
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Kiat Ho",
                            "id": 6917
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Overall Experience",
                            "id": 6918
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "level_1_name": "CiscoLondonEBC",
                    "level_2": [
                    {
                        "level_2_name": "Bernard Mathews Ltd.",
                        "level_2_id": 2367,
                        "level_3": [
                        {
                            "name": "Barry Pascolutti",
                            "id": 7193
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Kathrine Eilersten",
                            "id": 7194
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Martin Rowley",
                            "id": 7189
                        }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "level_2_name": "FNHW Day 1",
                        "level_2_id": 5678,
                        "level_3": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jurgen Gosch",
                            "id": 7834
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Overall Experience",
                            "id": 7835
                        }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "level_2_name": "Groupe Steria Day 1",
                        "level_2_id": 2789,
                        "level_3": [
                        {
                            "name": "Adam Philpott",
                            "id": 7919
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Pranav Kumar",
                            "id": 7921
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Steve Simlo",
                            "id": 7928
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                }
                ]
            };
enter code here
```

Comment: That's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/vva3g3m8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I am interpretting your request correctly, but I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/mooreinteractive/43jh9hzz/1/

Basically, you are calling the iterate function to run, but then that's it. The function actually needs to also return the value it generates.

I've added to the end of the function, after the for loop completes:

```
return json;
```

Do now the function returns the value it generated, but there are some other issues too. When you recursively call the iterate function again inside the iterate function, you actually want to add what it returns to the current json string housing all of your returned value.

So on that line I changed it from:

```
iterate(obj[property], stack + '.' + property);
```

to

```
json += iterate(obj[property], stack + '.' + property);
```

Now that other value will come back as well inside the main list you were creating in the first run of the function. Ok so that's pretty close, but one more small thing. I think when you added additional surrounding LI, you actually wanted to do an UL. I changed those to ULs and now I think the result is like a UL/LI list representing the text parts of the JSON object.

Again, that may not be exactly what you were after, but I think the main take away is using the function to return the value, not just generate it, then do nothing with it.

Comment: You are correct, I've been trying to generate and remove the extra markup that is not required to display the nested ul and it's children li's,  the main issue was to push the values into an html, thank you so much for your help, I think I can start styling the list to only ul's that have a direct li children @FunkyKnuck